# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type record

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT * " +
            "FROM chores WHERE id in (SELECT a.id " +
            "FROM chores as a INNER JOIN chores_assign_users as b ON a.id=b.chore_id " +
            "WHERE (a.is_deleted=FALSE " +
            "AND a.family_id=:familyId " +
            "AND (:userId IS NULL OR (cast(b.user_id as VARCHAR) IN :userId)) " +
            "AND (:status IS NULL OR (a.status IN :status)) " +
            "AND (:title IS NULL OR a.title LIKE cast(:title as text)) " +
            "AND (:from IS NULL OR :to IS NULL OR cast(created_at as VARCHAR) >= :from AND cast(created_at as VARCHAR) <= :to)) " +
            "ORDER BY :sortByDeadline" +
            ", CASE WHEN :sortByDeadline THEN a.deadline END DESC " +
            ", CASE WHEN NOT :sortByDeadline THEN a.created_at END DESC)",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) FROM chores as a INNER JOIN chores_assign_users as b ON a.id=b.chore_id " +
                    "WHERE a.is_deleted=FALSE " +
                    "AND a.family_id=:familyId " +
                    "AND (:userId IS NULL OR (cast(b.user_id as VARCHAR) IN (:userId))) " +
                    "AND (:status IS NULL OR (a.status IN (:status))) " +
                    "AND (:title IS NULL OR a.title LIKE cast(:title as text))" +
                    "AND (:from IS NULL OR :to IS NULL OR cast(created_at as VARCHAR) >= :from AND cast(created_at as VARCHAR) <= :to)) ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    ArrayList<Chore> findAlLFilteredByUserAndStatusAndTitleSortedByCreatedAtOrDeadLine(@Param("familyId") int familyId,
                                                                                       @Param("userId") List<String> userId,
                                                                                       @Param("status") List<String> status,
                                                                                       @Param("title") String title,
                                                                                       @Param("sortByDeadline") boolean sortByDeadline,
                                                                                       @Param("from") String from,
                                                                                       @Param("to") String to,
                                                                                       Pageable pageable);
```

I have this native query in a jpa repository. As you can see, I search for the records which have `user_id IN :userId`. This works fine as long as `userId` contains only one element. But if `userId` contains more than one element, this exception will be thrown `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type record`. The same problem happens to `"AND (:status IS NULL OR (a.status IN :status)) "`

`user_id` has type integer

`status` has type varchar

I am having a hard time finding a way to fix this. Could you please help me with this? And also, is it good to pass a List of integers to the query as a list of string by converting every elements to string just like I do with `userId` in this case? Can it be the problem and how can I fix it? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type record.` The same problem happens to `"AND (:status IS NULL OR (a.status IN :status)) "`

I think using `COALESCE(:status) IS NULL` instead of `:status IS NULL` will solve above problem.

Comment: Yes sir! ```COALESCE(:status) IS NULL``` got it done, it works for ```AND (:userId IS NULL OR (cast(b.user_id as VARCHAR) IN :userId))```, too. Thank you so much !

Comment: @TrọngNghĩaLêĐình is this work with null status . i am facing the error if status is null any help will be appreciated